# Spark java - How to store java object in spark dataframe?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using spark in java and I want to store java objects in spark dataframe. I've searched many blogs and links but couldn't find a way to do this. Let's say my object class is -

```
class Temporary{
    Integer id;
    String name;
    String another;

    public Temporary(Integer id, String name, String another){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.another = another;
    }
}
```

I have a dataframe df and I want to store an object of this Temporary class in a column. Assume I am adding a column `Temporary` of array type that will have objects of Temporary class. I want to do something like-

```
df = df.withColumn("Temporary", functions.array(
                               functions.expr("CASE WHEN something_is_true THEN Temporary(1,"john","tempstring") ELSE empty_object END"),
                               functions.expr("CASE WHEN something_else_is_true THEN Temporary(2,"johny","tempstring") ELSE empty_object END")
                              ));

// expected result would be 

+------------------------------------------+
|                Temprorary                |
+------------------------------------------+
|  [Temproary_class_object, empty_object]  |
+------------------------------------------+
```

I know this will not work because expr only accepts a SQL string and not objects. Any way to do this? Any help would be appreciated.